# select product with minimum sale with partition

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have product table with columns Sale,Name Week as below :

```
sale | name  | week
-----+-------+-----------
8    | Fruit | 2017-03-01
64   | Fruit | 2017-02-01
-27  | Mango | 2018-01-01
1    | APPLE | 2018-01-01
0    | APPLE | 2018-02-01
10   | APPLE | 2018-03-01
50   | APPLE | 2018-04-01
80   | APPLE | 2018-05-01
```

I need the output as below

```
sale | name  | week
-----+-------+-----------
8    | Fruit | 2017-03-01
-27  | Mango | 2018-01-01
0    | APPLE | 2018-02-01
```

I have achieved this using `ROW_Number` with query:

```
select name, week, sale
from (
  select Row_Number() over (partition by name order by sale) as id
    , week
    , sale
    , name
  from test
) a
where id = 1
```

I just need the same output result WITHOUT using `partition/ROW_NUMBER`. Is there any to achieve the output using `join`?

Comment: mysql <> sql-server <> postgresql <> apache-spark-sql. Please don't spam the database tags, only tag the database that you are actually using.

Comment: @AnkusSharma . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: i have added it,because I am working in all above mentioned storage tools and solution in any storage platform will work for me .Please do not edit it unless required

Comment: @AnkurSharma: then tagging it with `sql` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from test t
where t.sale = (select min(t1.sale) from test t1 where t1.name = t.name)
```

Depending on your database and dataset, this might actually perform equally good or better than the window function solution, if you have an index on `(name, sale)`.

Comment: where t1.name = t.name, so inner query is matching each name with outer query ?

Comment: @AnkurSharma: yes, exactly. That's a *correlation* condition between the subquery and the outer query.